# SQL Server: Using Service Broker to parallely run several stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I need to use Service Broker in order to run several stored procedures parallelly (instead of sequentially). Please be aware that I need to use Service Broker, not alternative solutions such as SSIS or SQL Agent Jobs. I use SQL Server 13.0 (2016), SSMS 19.0 as well as AdventureWorksDW2016 as a database.

Unfortunately, the very few implementations I could find online do not work for me. Also I have tried writing a script myself. I do not really get any issues, however, I have provided a table to store the starttime and endtime of my procedures, and unfortunately when I execute the procedures, I can see that they are being executing after the procedure before is finished.

My script looks like so: Do you see what I am doing wrong or do you perhaps have a good implementation online? The ones that I have found, did not really help me.

```
-- enable Service Broker; might be enabled by default
--alter database [AdventureWorksDW2016_2] set enable_broker with rollback immediate;

--Create a Service Broker queue and service for the stored procedure:
CREATE QUEUE parallel_proc_queue;
CREATE SERVICE parallel_proc_service ON QUEUE parallel_proc_queue;

--Create a stored procedure that sends a message to the Service Broker queue and executes the desired stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE send_parallel_proc_message
  @proc_name VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
  
  BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @conversation_handle
    FROM SERVICE parallel_proc_service
    TO SERVICE 'parallel_proc_service'
    ON CONTRACT parallel_proc_contract
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
  
  SEND ON CONVERSATION @conversation_handle
    MESSAGE TYPE parallel_proc_message
    (@proc_name);
  
  EXECUTE @proc_name;
  
  END CONVERSATION @conversation_handle;
END 


--Create a stored procedure that receives messages from the Service Broker queue and executes the stored procedure specified in the message:
CREATE PROCEDURE parallel_proc_receiver
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @message_body VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
  
  WHILE (1=1)
  BEGIN
    WAITFOR (
      RECEIVE TOP(1)
        @message_body = message_body,
        @conversation_handle = conversation_handle
      FROM parallel_proc_queue
    ), TIMEOUT 1000;
  
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
      BREAK;
  
    EXECUTE @message_body;
  
    END CONVERSATION @conversation_handle;
  END
END


-- define the contract for the Service Broker conversation
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE parallel_proc_message
  VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;

CREATE CONTRACT parallel_proc_contract
  (parallel_proc_message SENT BY ANY);


--Start the Service Broker conversation
DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @conversation_handle
  FROM SERVICE parallel_proc_service
  TO SERVICE 'parallel_proc_service'
  ON CONTRACT parallel_proc_contract
  WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF
BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (@conversation_handle) TIMEOUT = 180000; -- 3 minutes


--create table to measure time (to check if parallellity actually works)
CREATE TABLE dbo.StoredProcedureLog (
    SPName NVARCHAR(255),
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME
);


--define stored procedures 
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetSalesForCustomer
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
    -- Log the start time of the stored procedure
    INSERT INTO dbo.StoredProcedureLog (SPName, StartTime)
    VALUES ('usp_GetSalesForCustomer', GETDATE());

    SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, SUM(f.SalesAmount) AS TotalSales
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales f
    JOIN dbo.DimCustomer c ON c.CustomerKey = f.CustomerKey
    GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName;

    -- Log the end time of the stored procedure
    UPDATE dbo.StoredProcedureLog
    SET EndTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE SPName = 'usp_GetSalesForCustomer' AND EndTime IS NULL;
END



CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetProductSales
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:04';
    -- Log the start time of the stored procedure
    INSERT INTO dbo.StoredProcedureLog (SPName, StartTime)
    VALUES ('usp_GetProductSales', GETDATE());

    SELECT p.EnglishProductName, SUM(f.SalesAmount) AS TotalSales
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales f
    JOIN dbo.DimProduct p ON p.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
    GROUP BY p.EnglishProductName;

    -- Log the end time of the stored procedure
    UPDATE dbo.StoredProcedureLog
    SET EndTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE SPName = 'usp_GetProductSales' AND EndTime IS NULL;
END


CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetTopSellingProducts
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:06';
    -- Log the start time of the stored procedure
    INSERT INTO dbo.StoredProcedureLog (SPName, StartTime)
    VALUES ('usp_GetTopSellingProducts', GETDATE());

    SELECT TOP 10 p.EnglishProductName, SUM(f.SalesAmount) AS TotalSales
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales f
    JOIN dbo.DimProduct p ON p.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
    GROUP BY p.EnglishProductName
    ORDER BY TotalSales DESC;

    -- Log the end time of the stored procedure
    UPDATE dbo.StoredProcedureLog
    SET EndTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE SPName = 'usp_GetTopSellingProducts' AND EndTime IS NULL;
END

--Call the send_parallel_proc_message procedure for each stored procedure you want to execute in parallel:
EXEC dbo.send_parallel_proc_message 'usp_GetSalesForCustomer';
EXEC dbo.send_parallel_proc_message 'usp_GetProductSales';
EXEC dbo.send_parallel_proc_message 'usp_GetTopSellingProducts';


--Start the parallel_proc_receiver stored procedure to execute the stored procedures in parallel
EXEC parallel_proc_receiver;

--check start and endtime of procedures, starttime should be the same
select * from StoredProcedureLog
```

Answer (score 4):

Per `CREATE QUEUE` on the [Learn site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-queue-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#max_queue_readers-max_readers);

> MAX_QUEUE_READERS =max_readers

> Specifies the maximum number of instances of the activation stored procedure that the queue starts at the same time. The value of max_readers must be a number between 0 and 32767.

Configure the queue with three queue readers, and see if that helps.

Since you have defined the queue without specifying `RETENTION = ON`, you don't need to explicitly start and end conversations, unless you want to send completion messages back the sender.  Messages in the queue will be automatically removed from the queue once they have been received by the `WAITFOR...RECEIVE` statement.  See [this Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-queue-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#retention) for details about the `RETENTION` option.

Comment: As an aside, take a look at https://isitservicebroker.com

Comment: Hi Hannah,
thx for your reply. I have altered the queue like so:
ALTER QUEUE parallel_proc_queue
WITH ACTIVATION (
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 3);
However, the procedures still start sequentially.
Am I correct in assuming that EXEC parallel_proc_receiver; only needs to be executed once and afterwards I may execute 
EXEC dbo.send_parallel_proc_message 'usp_GetSalesForCustomer';
EXEC dbo.send_parallel_proc_message 'usp_GetProductSales';
EXEC dbo.send_para...
again, expecting them to run parallely?
Do I perhaps have to checks some settings of my DB? CPUs, Cores, is_broker_enabled?

Comment: You don't need to manually run the receiver proc at all.  SQL Server Service Broker handles running it whenever a message is waiting in the queue.  And yes, you need service broker enabled in the database where the service broker queues etc reside

Comment: Also, you should mske very sure that no one except authorized processes can send messages to the queue because the receiver proc will execute everything it receives.  See https://xkcd.com/327/ for an example.

Comment: The `WAITFOR DELAY` statements in your three test procs should probably be after the start time is recorded, and before the end time is recorded.